# How to send number with country code to url of browser from mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Wrote this code in view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CDR)
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a class="facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=@item.BNumber">Facebook</a>
            <a class="facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.truecaller.com/pk/@item.BNumber">True Caller</a>
        </th>
```

When I click on this number,

it gets automatically send  to url and

url automatically identify this number's country code ...

My **Problem** :

When I send the number Url is not identifying its country code.

Tell me how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The first few things to check would be the standards, how are you passing this modal. In the controller or do you have a separate ViewModel class?

Something you might want to add is a check

Assuming `Model.CDR` is a **List** or **Enumerable**

Another thing you should do is have the **type** of CDR.

Easiest way to do this if you are struggling is *(If using Visual Studio)* put a break point in at the `@foreach` line and in your watch, call `Model.CDR` to see what type it is passing back.

That will allow you to strongly type it in your foreach statement, makes the whole thing a heap easier.

```
@if (Model.CDR.Length != 0)
{
  @foreach (object //CHANGE OBJECT TO YOUR TYPE// item in Model.CDR){

  }
}
```

If you send in a little more info on what your Model looks like, how the CDR object is constructed I could help you a little more.